# Matrix representation of the linear operator $A = \frac{d}{dx} + x \frac{d}{dx}$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

$A = \frac{d}{dx} + x \frac{d}{dx}$ is an operator that acts on the vector space $P^n$ of all real valued polynomials of degree $\le n$. with respect to the standard basis $\{x_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}_0}$.
To find the linear operator I checked the "effect" of the operator on the basis:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(x^0) + x \frac{d}{dx} (x^0) = 0  \\
\frac{d}{dx}(x^1) + x \frac{d}{dx} (x^1) = 1 + x \\
\frac{d}{dx}(x^2) + x \frac{d}{dx} (x^2) = 0 + 2x + 2x^2 \\
\frac{d}{dx}(x^3) + x \frac{d}{dx} (x^3) = 0 + 0 + 3x^2 + 3x^3 $$

From here I concluded that in 4-dimension the operator would be represented by the matrix: 
$$\left[ \begin {array}{cccc} 0&1&0&0\\ 0&1&2&0
\\ 0&0&2&3\\ {}0&0&0&3\end {array}
 \right] $$

but the correct seems to "exclude" the first column of zeros and instead the four dimension matrix is "a shift" to the left with the fourth column being: $[0,0,0,4]$.
Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You didn't. Indeed, the shifted version has non-zero determinant, so is the matrix of an injective linear map, which this clearly is not.

Comment: $x^4$ should also be in your basis making it a 5x5 matrix. $x^0$ should only be omitted if we have $\mathbb N_{>0}$. It's not unusual that there is ambiguity there. Does your text define $\mathbb N_0$?

Comment: @IlikeSerena unfortunately no but it mentions a vector in this space is $p(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + ...+ a_n x^n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you did looks fine to me, if you are using the basis $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ for what you call $P^3$. (Are you certain that is the basis the book expects?)

Anywayno matter what the basis is supposed to be, the "shifted" answer you describe cannot be correct. It is nonsingular, but this operator annihilates nonzero constant functions.

Comment: Say $A$ acted on the vector $[2,3,4,5]$ then I would get $[3, 11, 23, 15])$ correct?

Comment: Yes. That is like $(\frac{d}{dx}+x\frac{d}{dx})(2+3x+4x^2+5x^3)$, which equals $3+11x+23x^2+15x^3$. And that matches your output vector.